# Verifying a G Suite domain through the api

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I have created a domain trough the Directory API in Java. Now I need to verify this domain before I can add users to it. Can this be done through the Admin SDK Api's?

Comment: Are you looking for email domain verification? right?

Comment: Yes, for G Suite specifically

Comment: i have added a domain using golang admin sdk but unable to figure out how to verify the domain using the sdk. Basically I need either the TXT record or the cname record and then I can take care of updating the dns zone.